# How big is the baalei tshuva movement resulting from the "Art Scroll Revolution"?

Tags: history, jewish-books, baal-teshuva, artscroll

Since 1975, Art Scroll Publishing, and its non-profit arm The Mesorah Foundation, have produced Hebrew-English annotated translations of Tanach, the Mishna, the Babylonian Talmud, the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch. siddurim, machzorim, biographies and several tractates of the Jerusalem Talmud.  These books have opened tremendous opportunities for Jews not raised in a yeshiva environment to learn Talmud and halacha at a much higher level than ever before, and has been termed by some as ["The Art Scroll Revolution."](http://matzav.com/the-artscroll-revolution-5tjt-interviews-rabbi-nosson-scherman) See, e.g. Jeremy Stolow, *Orthodox by Design: Judaism, Print Politics, and the ArtScroll Revolution* (2010).

Has anyone ever quantified, in any terms, the effect on the baalei t'shuva movement that Art Scroll has had?

Comment: I am not sure how a person could quantify the effect of Artscroll on the Baal Teshuva movement. Baalei Teshuva are generally influenced by a multitude of factors, Artscroll being one of them.

Comment: @LN6595 I think that the question I pose is one of a type that Sociologists would be familiar with.  You can quantify book sales and mark them in time; you can quantify (over time) growth in Orthodox synagogue membership, growth in Jewish day schools, and growth of Kosher restaurants, for example.  I think there are also estimates of daf yomi participation out there too.  Plenty of info for a PhD candidate with time and patience.  But the answer may be "not yet" as no one has yet tried to tackle the research.

Comment: @LN6595, conceivably, one could do a sociological study testing the hypothesis, for example, that all other things held constant, a Jew who had exposure to ArtScroll books was more likely to increase his measurable Jewish observance than one who didn't. The gradual release of more and more ArtScroll offerings and the fact that some languages (English) got ArtScroll books before others could  provide other means of controlling the analysis.

Comment: @IsaacMoses this type of research also would come out in a detailed marketing study.

Comment: @BruceJameshas anybody quantified the term ba'al tshuva? Does it mean a particular increase in practice, or belief? What if someone starts off as "Conservative" and then becomes Orthodox -- is that different from starting an atheist? Is it about self identification? Artscroll has helped people across the spectrum accomplish something but when does it count as effecting a becoming ba'al tshuva?

Comment: @BruceJames I don't think the previous comment pinged you.

Comment: @danno - It occurs to me that the study would define the term or otherwise describe the scope of the universe it is testing.